# How to copy to clipboard from multiple fields of a form

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, dom-events

```
<TEXTAREA ID="holdtext" >

</TEXTAREA>
<input ID="holdtext1" type="text">

<BUTTON onClick="ClipBoard();">Copy to Clipboard</BUTTON>

<SCRIPT LANGUAGE="JavaScript">

function ClipBoard(){
    Copied = holdtext.createTextRange();
    Copied1 = holdtext1.createTextRange();
    Copied.execCommand("RemoveFormat");
    Copied.execCommand("Copy");
    Copied1.execCommand("RemoveFormat");
    Copied1.execCommand("Copy");
}

</SCRIPT>
```

Here I am not able to copy both the fields. I am able to copy from a single field but
my form has multiple fields. Please help me out.

Answer (score 2):

[window.clipboardData.setData()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms536744%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) may be interesting to you:

```
    window.clipboardData.setData('text',
                          document.getElementById('holdtext').value + 
                          document.getElementById('holdtext1').value
                         );
```

If you like to do it using a textRange you may set the [**text**-property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms534676%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) of the textRange:

```
function ClipBoard() 
{
    //create a new element, otherwise setting of range.text 
    //will change the form-fields values
    var dummy=document.createElement('textarea');

    //the range
   Copied = dummy.createTextRange();

   //set the text
   Copied.text = document.getElementById('holdtext').value +
                 document.getElementById('holdtext1').value;

   //expand the range to contain all contents
   Copied.expand('textedit');

   //useless, because textarea's contents doesn't apply formatting
   Copied.execCommand("RemoveFormat");

   //Copy
   Copied.execCommand("Copy");
}
```

But always keep in mind: accessing the clipBoard may end in lost data, you'll never know what's currently inside the clipBoard.
**You really shouldn't access the clipBoard from a webpage.**

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried concatenating both strings, then copying that?

```
copied = holdtext.createTextRange();
copiedOne = holdtext1.createTextRange();
allCopied = copied + copiedOne;
allCopied.execCommand("RemoveFormat");
allCopied.execCommand("Copy");
```

Comment: could you paste a working example (with just one field) on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/)?

Comment: @Alex: try  OPs code using IE, this will only work in IE and only when IE allows scripting-access to the clipboard.